# Add two same images for every two divs in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, append, slice

I have an array of images and an array of divs. And I want to add the same image for the first two divs and add second images from the array for 3rd and fourth div and repeat that few times.
Code below does the job but is there any simpler way to do it:

```
var images = [image1, image2, image3, image4,.....];
var allDivs = $('.div-images');

allDivs.slice(0, 2).append(images[0]);
allDivs.slice(2, 4).append(images[1]);
allDivs.slice(4, 6).append(images[2]);
allDivs.slice(6, 8).append(images[3]);
allDivs.slice(8, 10).append(images[4]);
```

Comment: Pretty sure you could do this with a `for` loop... `allDivs.slice(i*2, i*2+2).append(images[i])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement the logic dynamically you can use a `forEach()` loop through the `images` array. From there you can use the current index of the loop to retrieve the element from `$allDivs` at that index, as well as it's following sibling, before appending the value to both of them. Try this:

```js
var images = ['image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4', 'image5'];
var $allDivs = $('.div-images');

images.forEach((image, i) => $allDivs.eq(i * 2).next().addBack().append(image));
```

```css
/* CSS for demo purposes only, to make the grouping clearer */
.div-images { 
  border: 1px solid #C00;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.div-images:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-images"></div>
<div class="div-images"></div>
<div class="div-images"></div>
<div class="div-images"></div>
<div class="div-images"></div>
<div class="div-images"></div>
<div class="div-images"></div>
<div class="div-images"></div>
<div class="div-images"></div>
<div class="div-images"></div>
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @OsvaldasŽadeikis if you are happy with this answer. please consider accepting by clicking the green check mark on side. So that this will help other in future. How to accept an answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235